# Possible refresh faster than a second?

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can make my PHP Meta refresh, faster than a second.

```
if( (int) $page > 0 ) {
  print '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=index.php?id='.($page-1).'">';
}
```

Right now, its a little slow.

Comment: Why would you want to?? What is the purpose of your refresh, in this case? Maybe there's a more appropriate solution to your requirement.

Comment: @ADyson I am downloading many images from external site / using page down - up modifiers

Comment: I'm not sure how downloading some files is relevant to a meta refresh? Please edit your question to give the full context for what you're trying to do.

Comment: in javascript there is something known as setTimeout and setInterval (they can handle things in milliseconds). But as ADyson has said - what is the relationship between refresh rate and downloading a file ?

Comment: @KenLee it will take a lot for me to explain it - but basically $page is = to an identifier / that identifier goes down, using the code shown above, and navigates to a secondary page to download the contents there / I wanna do the same thing, but faster

Comment: You should come up with a reasonably succint explanation of what you're _actually_ trying to do here and post _that_ as a question, because it sounds like you are trying to accomplish something fairly simple but in a fairly bizarre way.